# UIProgressView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Please any one help me. How to implement UIProgressView in iPhone with some simple application with source.

Comment: if you need a tutorial, please consider using Google.

Answer (score 1):

[`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) comes with a sample project that uses a `UIProgressView` to mark download progress. But using Google is also a good idea.